# Django - NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-registration

I'm trying to implement and Login and Registration system for my Django project. I'm currently getting this error...

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'register' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is some of my code so hopefully you can help....

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^stocks/$', StockView.as_view(), name='stocks'),
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
#url(r'^data/$', DataView.as_view(), name='data'),
url(r'^quizzes/$', DefView.as_view(), name='quizzes'),
url(r'^tickers/$', DefView.as_view(), name='ticker'),

url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'stockmarket.views.login'),
url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'stockmarket.views.auth_view'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'stockmarket.views.logout'),
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'stockmarket.views.loggedin'),
url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'stockmarket.views.invalid_login'),

url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'stockmarket.views.register_user'),
url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'stockmarket.views.register_success'),
```

]

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)


def auth_view(request):
    username = reqruest.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')


def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html', {'full_name': request.user.username})


def invalid_login(request):
    return render_to_response('invalid_login.html')


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render_to_response('logout.html')


def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)


def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your project you used django's urlresolvers to return url for using a named url called `'register'`.

After seeing your `urls.py`, it appears that you don't have any url with `register` named assigned to it. You should named it where it is appropriate.. something like this:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'stockmarket.views.register_user', name='register'),
```